# CSS nth-child all elements appearing as "odd"

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

I've got a table of HTML & CSS, and want to apply the n-th child selector so that I can alternate colours between table rows.

For some reason, every row is displaying as the same color.

A similar question on Stack Overflow says that the n-th child selector applies not to the child but to the element itself. I understand this, and I have another table class which works properly, but my second table class that I want to apply this to does not work.

I have tried applying the WORKING table class to several tables. On some tables, it works, on others, it does not.

CSS:

```
.prevTable{
    table-layout: fixed;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    padding: 3px;
    border-radius: 3px;
    font-size: 13px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 860px;
}
.prevTable th{
    padding: 6px 3px 6px 3px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
    font-family: Raleway;
    text-align: center;
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid gray;
}
.prevTable td{
    padding:5px;
    font-family: Raleway;
    border: 1px solid gray;
    text-align:left;
}
table.prevTable tr:nth-child(even){
    background-color: #E6E6E6;
}
table.prevTable tr:nth-child(odd){
    background-color: #C9C9C9;
}
```

HTML TABLE:

```
<table class="prevTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Parameter</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
             <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
             <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
             <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
             <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
        </tbody>
</table>
```

MY FIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/vranvs/dhnJ9/

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: 'Some content' is, presumably wrapped in a `<td>` element?

Comment: indeed! sorry for excluding that

Comment: When I use `<td>` tags, it works for me in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/qHh8v/

Comment: It might be worth editing the question to clarify that.

Comment: Why don't you just set the background color on the table one color and the only target even or odd with the alternate color?

Comment: The problem must be with my HTML... because i just pasted my HTML table in JS fiddle and I'm getting the same problem.

Comment: Please edit your question with the fiddle.

Comment: Here is my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/vranvs/dhnJ9/

Comment: Wow I'm an idiot, I was using <tr/> tags, as opposed to </tr>. Sorry everybody :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/y9wsg/1/

http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_tables.asp

```
<table class="prevTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Parameter</th>
            <th>Value</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
<tbody>
     <tr><td>tr = tablerow</td></tr>
     <tr><td>need a td = table cell (or table data)</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

was to slow :>

Answer (score 2):

You need to wrap them in table data, td

```
<tbody>
     <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
     <tr><td>Some Content</td></tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem appeared to be that the HTML was lacking `<td>` tags. The CSS works if those tags are in the HTML, as shown here: http://jsfiddle.net/qHh8v/